# how to call a function from another function in matlab

Tags: matlab

Actually, I have two m-files: one is primary and other one is secondary.
The `primary` m-file contains just a formula for now.  I am trying to pass 4 input arguments to it through the `secondary` m-file, but I am getting an error about too many arguments when I run the `secondary` program.

```
     function[]=primary(A,omega,t,angle)
     A.*sin(omega*t+angle);
     end
```

For secondary:

```
    function[n]=secondary(A,omega,t,angle)
    A=input('enter the value of amplitude\n');
    omega=input('enter the value of omega\n');
    t=input('enter the value of time interval\n');
    angle=input('enter the value of angle\n');
    angle=(angle*pi)/180;
    n=primary(A,omega,t,angle);
    T=-t:t;
    plot(T,n);
    end
```

Comment: Woah. Please first learn to use `function` inside MATLAB. You cannot assign variables which you input in the `function` call (1.e. the first line) itself. So all your `input` calls are invalid.

Comment: In addition to my answer, which should fix the error, @Adriaan is correct that declaring `A`, `omega`, `t`, and `angle` as function arguments that are immediately overridden by the `input` lines is a poor use of functions.  Either call `secondary` passing the inputs **or** use `input` to a define their values but not both (I would say passing as arguments is better).

Answer (score 1):

The function `primary` does not declare any output arguments; therefore, the line `n=primary(A,omega,t,angle);` in `secondary` will throw an error due to too many output arguments.

Change the definition of primary to include an output:

```
 function [n] = primary(A,omega,t,angle)
   n = A.*sin(omega*t+angle);
 end
```